# Does Selenium register key strokes and move movement in productivity tracking software?

Tags: macos, selenium

Take a look at something like this: https://www.rescuetime.com/

If I use Selenium and load a website and type some info and click some elements, would it register in something like that?

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. Do you just want to know if some type/click with selenium will register? Or you want to know how selenium can be used to make those activity to register on that type of site? If the first one, then I will say the answer probably is no, because I had tried with sendKeys/ click methods on a site, but it does not take these as activities. But I had not researched enough to tell the reason behind that or workaround. Hope this helps! I will provide you the code if you want!

Comment: Which exactly software for productivity tracking do you use?

Comment: @DenisKoreyba did you read the question?

Comment: @User no one understood your question. You can see it by the answers.

Comment: It's hard to answer the question as it is written. "If I use Selenium and load a website and type some info". The most frequently used part of Selenium is the WebDriver which is a library to write tests. So you won't be using and typing in the Website, you will write tests to do that. The part about registering is also unclear. Unless you are looking for a program and not a test writing library which is why I suggested you use the Selenium IDE.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the EventFiringWebdriver.

Example implementation https://gist.github.com/krmahadevan/1728633

Basically, EventFiringWebdriver raises events before and after various actions. And your code can provide event handlers and do whatever you need to at that point.